# PYQT5 - Update a label when a QPushButton is checked/unchecked

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

How do I change the text of a label when QPushButton with `checkable` set to True is checked or unchecked.
I am using the buttons as a seat selection chart and on clicking a certain seat I want to update a label(or, if possible something else) that will show the price based on seat selection, and would deduct the value when its unchecked.

the code for the seats:

```
        vipseats = QButtonGroup()
        for i in range(1, 41):
            vseat = QPushButton(self.centralwidget, checkable = True)
            vipseats.addButton(vseat)
            if i <= 20:
                labelm = QLabel(f'V-A-{i}', self.centralwidget)
                labelm.setGeometry(QRect(280+ 60* i, 550, 50, 50))
                vseat.setGeometry(QRect(280+ 60* i, 550, 50, 50))
            elif 20 < i <= 41:
                labelm = QLabel(f'V-B-{i-20}', self.centralwidget)
                labelm.setGeometry(QRect(280+ 60* (i-20), 625, 50, 50))
                vseat.setGeometry(QRect(280+ 60* (i-20), 625, 50, 50))
```

[the seating chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptpS5.png)

Comment: [`QButtonGroup.buttonToggled`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html#buttonToggled)

Answer (score -1):

As musicamante mentioned in the comment, connect a slot or that will do what ever you want:

```
vseat.buttonToggled.connect(your_slot_function)
```

And impelent the changes inside slot func.

Comment: According to the OP, `vseat` is a button, so it doesn't have a `buttonToggled` signal and the above code will cause a crash due to a `AttributeError`. It should be `vipseats.buttonToggled.connect(your_slot_function)`. Please be more careful when providing answers.